# Design pattern? How to do "Abstract generator creating abstract instance"

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have two class hierarchies: config templates and config instances.
Config templates can generate config instances.
Example: creating pens from a set of possible configurations. Later on I might want to add pencils and markers, hence the hierarchy.

(Note: in the C++11 code below, I'm skipping the obvious includes, virtual destructors, "using namespace std" and such; the example and the question is about abstraction)

```
struct cConfigTemplate_WritingTool
{
    int length_range[2];
    string possible_shapes[] = {"circle", "octagon"};
};

struct cConfigInstance_WritingTool
{
    int length;
    string shape;
};

struct cConfigTemplate_Pen : public cConfigTemplate_WritingTool
{
    string ink_colours[] = {"red", "blue"};
    float chance_to_be_ball_point;
};

struct cConfigInstance_Pen : public cConfigInstance_WritingTool
{
    string ink_colour;
    bool is_ball_point;
};
```

My questions are:

- is this a good design? I need the hierarchy to add other configuration types that share parameters.
- if it's a bad design, how would you do it better? Is there a design pattern for this that I've missed? If yes, which and how does it get applied?
- how do I implement functionality to generate a cConfigInstance_WritingTool from a cConfigTemplate_WritingTool in an abstract way? e.g.

  `cConfigTemplate_WritingTool * tool_template = new cConfigTemplate_Pen();
   cConfigInstance_WritingTool * tool_instance = tool_template->generate_instance();`

Comment: it was not supposed to be compilable or sth, I just wanted to give an idea.

Comment: Oh well. This tends to happen when it looks like c++ and you tag it [tag:c++] and you mention C++ once more in your post.

Comment: ok made it a bit clearer

Answer (score -2):

> is this a good design?

Yes, it is a good design, is not bad, but, some improvement can be done. I prefer to use "class" instead of "struct".

**Before:**

```
struct cConfigTemplate_WritingTool
{
  int length_range[2];
  string possible_shapes = {"circle", "octagon"};
};
```

**After:**

```
public class cConfigTemplate_WritingTool
{
  public int length_range[2];
  public string possible_shapes = {"circle", "octagon"};
};
```

When using "class", you need to add the "public" keyword.

Another general suggestion, it's to use identifiers that are more meaningful.

**Before:**

```
struct cConfigTemplate_WritingTool
{
  int length_range[2];
  string possible_shapes = {"circle", "octagon"};
};

struct cConfigInstance_WritingTool
{
  public int length;
  public string shape;
};
```

**After:**

```
struct TemplateClass
{
  int length_range[2];
  string possible_shapes = {"circle", "octagon"};
};

struct ToolClass
{
  int length;
  string shape;
};
```

Altought, this is not a requirement, using identifiers, that are more meaningful, helps to describe a problem that is in your mind, into a real world, program / source code.

---

> if it's a bad design, how would you do it better?

Maybe you rush too early to abstract super classes, and tried to do the whole program at the time.

When designing hierarchies, you may want to start the opposite way. First design the "leaf" or "child" classes, without "super" classes, and later the "super" classes.

The following code examples are not fully C++ programs. Some code has been ommited, in order to make the answer, clear.

---

[1] You want to design a WritingTool Application.

Note, that is very common to add a "Universe" or "Application" object that wraps the whole program.

```
public /* concrete */ class WritingToolClass
{
  public:
    void Write() { ... }
} // class WritingToolClass

int main()
{
   WritingToolClass MyWritingTool = new WritingToolClass();

   MyWritingTool->Write();

   free MyWritingTool();
} // int main(...)
```

---

[2] On this application the users will use several tools with predefined features. The tools are objects, therefore, have a class definition. Examples of tools are "Pen", "Figure", "Brush", etc.

```
public /* concrete */ class WritingToolClass
{
  public:
    void Write() { ... }
} // class WritingToolClass

public /* concrete */ class PenClass
{
  public:
    void Write() { ... }
} // class PenClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushClass
{
  public:
    void Write() { ... }
} // class BrushClass

int main()
{
   WritingToolClass MyWritingTool = new WritingToolClass();

   MyWritingTool->Write();

   free MyWritingTool();
} // int main(...)
```

---

[3] Those tools, have properties, that are assigned at creation time.

```
...

public /* concrete*/ class PenClass
{
  protected:
    ColorType Color;
    int Width;
  public:
    /* constructor */ PenClass
      (ColorType AColor, int AWidth) 
        {
          this.Color = AColor;
          this.Width = AWidth;
        }
} // class PenClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushClass
{
  protected:
    ColorType Color;
  public:
    /* constructor */ PenClass
      (ColorType AColor) 
        {
          this.Color = AColor;
        }
} // class BrushClass

...
```

---

[4] In order to create tools, with the given features, the application has some special objects that are like the factories of the "Tools".

Let's call them "Templates".  For each category of tools, you need an specific "Template " or "Factory".

The template will provide you a specific tool, using a function called "generateInstance":

```
...

public /* concrete */ class PenClass
{
  // ...
} // class PenClass

public /* concrete */ class PenTemplateClass
{
  public:
    PenClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class PenTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushClass
{
  // ...
} // class BrushClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushTemplateClass
{
  public:
    BrushClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class BrushTemplateClass

...
```

Check that the "generateInstance" function of each template returns a different type. That will change later.

---

[5] The "Tools" are independent not related, concrete (not abstract) classes. It have several duplicated members, some of them omitted, in the examples. Let's add unleast an abstract super class for them.

```
...

public /* abstract */ class ToolClass
{
  /* replaceable */ virtual void Draw() { ... }
} // class ToolClass

public /* concrete */ class PenToolClass: public ToolClass
{
  /* replaced */ virtual void Draw() { ... }
} // class PenToolClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushToolClass: public ToolClass
{
  /* replaced */ virtual void Draw() { ... }
} // class BrushToolClass

public /* concrete */ class FontToolClass: public ToolClass
{
  /* replaced */ virtual void Draw() { ... }
} // class FontToolClass

...
```

Check the `PenClass` is renamed to `PenToolClass`, the sames goes for the other tools.

We even, add a new "FontToolClass" class. So, we now, have a small "Tool" class hierarchy.

---

[6] The same, applies to the "Tool" (s) factories called "Template" (s). Let's add an abstract class with code that is inherited by the concrete "Template" (s).

```
public /* abstract */ class ToolClass
{
  // ...
} // class ToolClass

public /* abstract */ class TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaceable */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class TemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class PenTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class PenTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class BrushTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class FontTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance() { ... }
} // class FontTemplateClass
```

Note, that the base class for "Template" (s) now, has a `generateInstance` function, that is `virtual`, and returns a `ToolClass` instead.

And, that the replaced `generateInstance` function in the concrete "Template" (s) classes also return an abstract type, but, in real world, it should return it matching "Tool" class.

> Is there a design pattern for this that I've missed? If yes, which and how does it get applied?

Note: The previous example is known as the "Factory" Software Design Pattern.

---

> how do I implement functionality to generate a
>   cConfigInstance_WritingTool from a cConfigTemplate_WritingTool in an
>   abstract way?

[7] First, this is done by defining a `virtual` ("replaceable") function in the "Template" (s) base class.

```
public /* abstract */ class TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaceable */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance() = 0;
} // class TemplateClass
```

The `= 0` means this function has no code, and is intended to be replaced in subclasses.

---

[8] And replacing wih a new "virtual" function in the subclasses of the "Template" (s) classes.

```
public /* concrete */ class PenToolTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    ColorType Color;
    int Width;
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance()
    {
      PenClass Result = new PenClass(this.Color, this.Width);
      return Result;
    }
} // class PenToolTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class BrushToolTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance()
    {
      // ...
    }
} // class BrushToolTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class FontToolTemplateClass: public TemplateClass
{
  public:
    /* replaced */ virtual ToolClass generateInstance()
    {
      // ...
    }
} // class FontToolTemplateClass

public /* concrete */ class WritingToolClass
{
  public:
    void Write()
    {
      PenTemplateClass MyPenTemplate = new PenTemplateClass();

      MyPenTemplate.Color = Blue;
      MyPenTemplate.Width = 1;
      PenToolClass MyBluePen = MyPenTemplate->generateInstance();
        MyBluePen.Write();
      free MyBluePen();

      MyPenTemplate.Color = Red;
      MyPenTemplate.Width = 2;
      PenToolClass MyRedPen = MyPenTemplate->generateInstance();
        MyRedPen.Write();
      free MyRedPen();

      MyBrushTemplate.Color = Green;
      BrushToolClass MyGreenBrush = MyPenTemplate->generateInstance();
        MyGreenBrush.Write();
      free MyGreenBrush();

      // and so on

      free MyPenTemplate();
    } // void Write(...)
} // class WritingToolClass

int main()
{
   WritingToolClass MyWritingTool = new WritingToolClass();

   MyWritingTool->Write();

   free MyWritingTool();
} // int main(...)
```

---

Designing a class hierarchy is not a trivial task. The previous C++ examples are not complete, just give a general ideal of your question.

Cheers.

Comment: wow, I'll need some time to absorb this, thanks for the detail!

Comment: ??? What language are you writing in? This doesn't seem to compile in any language I know.

Comment: @Babis Don't bother, umlcat high.

Comment: Wait wat. What. What? This is nowhere close to C++.

Comment: That `WritingToolClass` example is baffling for several different reasons. Where did you get this stuff from, umlcat?

Comment: The part about preferring `class` over `struct` really got me laughing out loud, but then it went downhill too fast.

Comment: @Jefffrrey As you already known, in C++, the keyword "struct" can be used to specify classes with public classes. Yet I prefer to use "class", and leave "struct" for records or "Plain Data Objects". And, to be more close to O.O.P. techniques ...